# What is this little hole in the ESP32 footprint?

Tags: pcb, esp32

https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/WiFi-Modules_Espressif-Systems-ESP32-PICO-MINI-02-N8R2_C2980306.html

The hole near pin1 is not in the datasheet but in the footprint.

[image: footprint]
[image: pcb]
Should I place it inside board area?

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a pin 1 indicator?

Answer (score 0):

[image: easyeda]

It is actually a silkscreen. (Pin1 indicator)

Comment: Actually, on the original graphic close-up there are two colors, so it is most likely a silk screen dot but also with a copper layer dot (pad) within. (So even if the silk screen layer were left off, like for a prototype, the dot would still be visible in copper).